# FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, file-io

I get this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\...\filename.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

using this code:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(path + date + time "filename.xml"));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
writer.write("data");
```

Path exists but directories for 'date' and 'time' need to be created. Application has full permissions on the directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is because I'm creating a subdirectory in which to write the files. So I currently have `C:\example\` and want to write my files in `C:\example\<date>\<time>\<files>`

You need to call [`File#mkdirs()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) before writing.

```
File file = new File("C:/example/newdir/newdir/filename.ext");
file.mkdirs();
// ...
```

Answer (score 4):

**Do assume that the computer is right and you are wrong.**

And, in that scenario, the directory to which you want to write does not exit (or does not have permissions to do so).

1. check the current working dir `System.getProperty("user.dir")`
2. debug from there

Comment: Yes, didn't assume otherwise. The problem is because I'm creating a subdirectory in which to write the files. So I currently have C:\example\ and want to write my files in C:\example\<date>\<time>\<files>

Answer (score 2):

Code works for me. (Need to add a `writer.close()` for text to show up in the file.)

Comment: Yes, works fine when writing to a directory that exists. Just found that the problem is because I'm writing in subdirectories that do not exist. I currently have C:\example\ and want to write my files in C:\example\<date>\<time>\<files>

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me: The folder where my project was present had a space in the name. I replacedthe space with a hyphen(-). Now, the relative path of the file does not have a space (%20). This change worked for me. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to convert newly created file and folder paths to string.

```
File folder = new File("src\\main\\json\\", idNumber);
    folder.mkdir();

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        try {
            folder.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JsonGeneration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
    FileOutputStream output = null;
        File file;
        String content = data.toString();

        try {

            String folder_location = folder.toString() + "\\";
            String filename = "CurrentInfo";
            file = new File(folder_location + filename.toString() + ".json");
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            byte[] content_in_bytes = content.getBytes();

            output.write(content_in_bytes);
            output.flush();
            output.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JsonGeneration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null) {
                    output.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(JsonGeneration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }

    }
```