# Error in uploading a file using Jersey rest service

Tags: rest, file-upload, jersey, multipartform-data

I am using jersey for building rest service which will upload a file. But I am facing problem in writing a file to required location. Java throws a system cannot find specified path error. Here is my Web service :

```
@POST
    @Path("/fileupload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file")InputStream fileUploadStream, @FormDataParam("file")FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) throws IOException{

        StringBuilder uploadFileLocation= new StringBuilder();

          uploadFileLocation.append("c:/logparser/webfrontend/uploads");
        uploadFileLocation.append("/"+dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        uploadFileLocation.append("/"+fileDetails.getFileName());
        writeToFile(fileUploadStream, uploadFileLocation.toString());
        return Response.status(200).entity("File saved to " + uploadFileLocation).build();
    }

    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadInputStream, String uploadFileLocation)
    {
        log.debug("UploadService , writeToFile method , start ()");

        try{
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[uploadInputStream.available()];

            log.info("UploadService, writeToFile method , copying uploaded files.");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.error("UploadService, writeToFile method, error in writing to file "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at just the code (it's usually helpful to include the exception and stack trace), you're trying to write to a directory based on a timestamp which doesn't exist yet.  Try adding a call to File.mkdir/mkdirs.  See this question/answer: [FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the path specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429527/filenotfoundexception-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)

Side note - Unless you have a reason not to, I'd consider using something like Apache commons-io(FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile) to do the writing.